# Trying to make a binary like system in an array -Wont Work

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am confused on how to go about the calculation, but when I tried it on a piece of paper, I found that I want to keep dividing the remainder with the next value in the array from left to right.

This is my function:

```
void getChange(int paid, int cost) {
    int r, k, s, cntr, c = 1, value[8], money[8] = {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};

    r = paid - cost;
    value[0] = r / money[0];
    k = r % money[0];                       
    for (money[c], cntr = 1; cntr < 8; c++, cntr++) {

        if (k !=0){
            value[c] = k / money[c];
            k = value[c] % money[c];
        } else{
            value[c] = 0;
            k = r / money[c + 1];
        }
    }

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%i \t", money[i]);
    }
    printf("\n \n");

    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
         printf("%i \t ", value[j]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is C? Should add the language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k = value[c] % money[c];` I think you mean `k = k % money[c];`. Also the else clause is kind of useless. The loop should break when `k == 0`.